# How do I display results on every table before going to the next record?

Tags: c#, rdlc

In C# rdlc, I have 2 datasets and one table displayed on the report for each dataset.

I need row 1 of dataset 1 to display in table 1, then row 1 of dataset 2 to display in table 2.

What happens is table 1 displays all the dataset items before moving the table 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that there is some "unifying" value in both datasets (or at least page number - which can be added to datasets too) that can be used in two ways:

1. Flatten the data. "Merge" data from both datasets to have values from the same page in the same row.
2. Create "main" report. Create "wrapper" dataset for the main with ids or page numbers to be passed to subrepors. Place table in main report for wrapper dataset. Create two subreports and "drop" them in rows 1 and 2 of the main report. Pass your id (page number) as a parameter to your subreport which would act as a "filter" for subreport data.

Second way sounds more complicated, but it can be justified if subreports are complex enough and/or have multiple rows for each id (page number).